# mongoose attempting to create index every time I start the server | Index with pattern: already exists with different options

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

my schema:

```
var courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String
    },
    instructors: {
        type: String
    },
    .
    .    
  fields: {type: [String], text: true},
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
});

courseSchema.index({title: 'text', subject: 'text', summary: 'text', syllabus: 'text'});

var Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);
module.exports = {Course};
```

searching text:

```
Course.find(
            { $text: { $search: req.query.title } },
            { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
        ).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } 

    )
```

when I start the server it gives the error:

```
MongoError: Index with pattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options
```

I have tried to drop the index by using

```
db.courses.dropIndex('title_text_subject_text_summary_text_syllabus_text');
```

**but when I restart the server, it again gives the same error and I can find that index with key _fts and _ftsx are already there.**

Which step am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

edit:
there was this field that I didn't add in the question which was creating the index. I removed it, its working fine.

```
fields: {type: [String], text: true},
```

Comment: which version of mongoose are you using ?

Comment: mongoose: 5.0.1
mongo db: 3.2.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: Don't create the index in the schema file. That will run every time you start your server and give the error you're seeing.

Index creation should be a maintenance task you execute in demand or otherwise only when you know you need to.

You could swap that for `ensureIndex` instead, but that's also recommended to be an on demand task, not an on server start task.

Answer (score 3):

I found my mistake. I was already creating an index in schema itself

```
fields: {type: [String], text: true},
```

after removing it, its working fine

Comment: mongodb throws an error on re-creating and index. how mongoose can recreate it. I think it's just a simple attempt and it will peacefully fails